# The number of active cases of COVID

Tags: covid-19

I have been looking at this URL for information about Covid:

[Graph of number of active cases of Covid](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/us/)

In particular, I am looking at the graph of the number of active cases. I would expect/hope that the number of active cases would be flat. Here is my reasoning. If the number of new Covid cases remains at a constant rate for a significant time, then the graph would be flat because there would be a constant recovery rate. However, with new drugs out for Covid, I would expect the recovery time to be less. In addition, in part because of vaccinations, I understand that the percentage of cases that need hospitalization are down. For these reasons, I would not expect the number of active cases of Covid to be at an all time high.

One possibility is that the data provided on the website is not right. I am thinking that might be the case because the patient goes to the doctor, the doctor diagnoses the problem as Covid and then treats the patient. This increases the number of active cases by one. The patient recovers and never sees the doctor again. As a result, the case is still considered active six months later because there was no follow up with the doctor.

I have looked around the web, and I could not find another site that provided a graph of the number of active cases verse time.

Please comment.

Comment: If your theory were right there would be no downturns in that graph. It would simply be a duplicate of the total cases graph.

Comment: At least in the UK, Christmas shopping! And when case numbers were lower traveling to see relatives as well. Cases also rocketed this time last year. They seem to reliably follow government policy and the populations behaviour, so keep an eye on the level/state of the Lockdown and during busy times like Holidays. It doesn't need a complete lockdown to work, but a complete lack of precautions does drive cases up. According to others projections a really unrealistically high level of face-mask use is also extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/about/

> Recoveries = this statistic is highly imperfect, because reporting can be missing, incomplete, incorrect, based on different definitions, or dated (or a combination of all of these) for many governments, both at the local and national level, sometimes with differences between states within the same country or counties within the same state. WHO recommends following the criteria of [symptoms resolve + 2 negative tests within 24 hours] or [symptoms resolve + additional 14 days], but this is only a recommendation. In some countries, when a patient is discharged from the hospital it is counted as "recovered" even if no test is performed. Some health officials now consider anyone who was diagnosed with COVID-19 three or more weeks ago and has not died to be recovered from the disease. In view of this, "Active Cases" and "Closed Cases Outcome" which both depend on the number of recoveries (in addition to an accurate death count and a satisfactory rate of case detection, both of which are lacking in the vast majority of countries) can be affected by this inherent flaw for many countries and for the total worldwide count

In summary, the "recoveries" statistic is a bit messy because of different definitions of recovery. They do not require a record of a case being recovered to count as such, though, if a case is not a death it is considered a recovery in 2-3 weeks.

It's best to interpret the graph of "active cases" as a moving average of infections; if "active cases" are at a high, that tells you that the number of infections over the past couple weeks is at a high. This is a pretty good measure of the recent virus activity.

I'm not sure I follow your logic of why you expect cases to not be at a high; right now, the high case rates are probably most influenced by spread of [variants like delta and omicron](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/variants/about-variants.html). While there are in fact a couple "new drugs" out for treating COVID, they are not in widespread use, and while vaccination seems to be protecting people who are vaccinated compared to their unvaccinated neighbors, there are still a lot of unvaccinated people (both by stubborn choice and by poor access in developing countries) and still a lot of spread.